# how to test a generator with unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have programmed a small iterator in Python:

```
class anything():
    def __init__(self):
        self.i=1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.i>100:
            raise StopIteration
        self.i=self.i+1
        return self.i
```

and I would like to use unittest of Python to check if some value on the generated list is even (I am just doing it for learning testing unit in Python). So I would like to have something like:

```
def main()
   for x in anything():
        assert x%2==0
```

but I just do not know how to accomplish that. I have read some material online, but there are no examples that teach how to manage the unit test within classes.

Comment: So you already read the Python docs about the unittest module, I guess? (https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) Tell us what you exactly is unclear for you in those example, then we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Below is an example of a test. BTW, you have a bug in your class. Probably `self.i=self.i+i` should be `self.i=self.i+1`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- Python -*-
"Unit test for Columnize"
import unittest
from it import anything

class TestI(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_basic(self):
        for x in anything():
            if x % 2 == 0:
                self.assertTrue(True, "Found value %d" % x)
                return
        self.assertTrue(False, "No even found in Anything")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```